# Yahoo Merchant Account - RTML - Preview a Template

Tags: yahoo, rtml

I'm editing a Yahoo store for a friend, and I feel like this is more complicated than it should be. I copied one of his templates and made some modifications, but I want to preview it before applying it to the live site... not sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have also same problem. No idea how to preview a modified Yahoo! store. While searching on the web, I have just find a [blog on yahoo store](http://www.ydeveloper.com/blog/category/yahoo-store) that can be helpful in terms of finding a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to a page in the editor and call your new template.  After you put your template name in the box and update, it will call your new template.  Nothing will be on the live site until you actually publish the store, so you can debug before publishing to the live site.  [image: Yahoo! Editor]